# How to read only number from a specific line using python script

Tags: python

How to read only number from a specific line using python script for example

"1009 run test jobs" here i should read only number "1009" instead of "1009 run test jobs"

Answer (score 1):

Or this if your number always comes first `int(line.split()[0])`

Answer (score 0):

a simple regexp should do:

```
import re
match = re.match(r"(\d+)", "1009 run test jobs")
if match:
    number = match.group()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "1009 run test jobs"
>>> re.sub("[^0-9]","",x)
>>> re.sub("\D","",x) #better way
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a simple check if its numbers in a string.

`[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]`

Where str is your string of text.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is a "more pythonic" way, but this works for me:

```
s='teststri3k2k3s21k'
outs=''
for i in s:
    try:
        numbr = int(i)
        outs+=i
    except:
        pass
print(outs)
```

If the number is always at the beginning of your string, you might consider something like `outstring = instring[0,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expression. That's very easy:

```
import re
regularExpression = "[^\d-]*(-?[0-9]+).*"
line = "some text -123 some text"
m = re.search(regularExpression, line)
if m:
    print(m.groups()[0])
```

This regular expression extracts the first number in a text. It considers `'-'` as part of numbers. If you don't want this change regular expression to this one: `"[^\d-]*([0-9]+).*"`